# how to configure Box2D in xcode

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

i want to add Box2D into my cocos2d 0.99.5 iphone/ipad project. I don't want to start new Box2D project from template.

I've added Box2D folder with Collision, Common & Dynamics, into my project and copied GLES-Render.h and .m and the license.
I also put '.' in front of "Header Search Path" in Project Info and changed AppDelegate.m to .mm .

When i compile it gives me 2543 error like "Box2D/Collision/Shapes/bCircleShape.h: No such file or directory".... please help why isn't it finding Box2d package and how to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, my mistake, when i added Box2D it was nested inside another folder "Box2D" i took it out and errors are reduced to 384. It's still unable to find some files like Cassert, Cmath Cfloat etc etc....

any solution?

Comment: and here's the final solution i found [link]http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/7985

Comment: +1 for solving your own problem and posting solution! Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: additional: you have to care that all classes that inherit from the class that have the #import in the header must have the file extension ".mm", too.